# Custom textarea editor

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, forms

I would like to transform the default textarea editor in my custom admin module with this module : https://github.com/Magenerds/PageDesigner

It is a module to create responsive content with CMS et block, it is perfectly working. Demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0wZzVPFhM0

Now, I need to use this functionnality in my custom module, I tried to modify the di.xml file to modify the behavior of my module, not result.

Default di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 */
 -->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Widget\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Form"
                type="\Magenerds\PageDesigner\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Form"/>
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState"
                type="Magenerds\PageDesigner\Model\ValidationState"/>
    <preference for="Magenerds\PageDesigner\Utils\HtmlRendererInterface"
                type="Magenerds\PageDesigner\Utils\HtmlRenderer"/>

    <!-- Plugins -->
    <type name="\Magento\Cms\Model\Page">
        <plugin name="Magenerds_PageDesigner::cmsPageRenderJson"
                type="Magenerds\PageDesigner\Plugin\Cms\Model\Page\PagePlugin" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Page\DataProvider">
        <plugin name="Magenerds_PageDesigner::injectPageHtmlIntoJson"
                type="Magenerds\PageDesigner\Plugin\Cms\Model\Page\DataProviderPlugin" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type>
    <type name="\Magento\Cms\Model\Block">
        <plugin name="Magenerds_PageDesigner::cmsBlockRenderJson"
                type="Magenerds\PageDesigner\Plugin\Cms\Model\Block\BlockPlugin" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Block\DataProvider">
        <plugin name="Magenerds_PageDesigner::injectPageHtmlIntoJson"
                type="Magenerds\PageDesigner\Plugin\Cms\Model\Block\DataProviderPlugin" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Widget\Model\Widget">
        <plugin name="Magenerds_PageDesigner::widgetEncode"
                type="Magenerds\PageDesigner\Plugin\Model\WidgetPlugin"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Widget\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Options">
        <plugin name="Magenerds_PageDesigner::widgetDecodeBackend"
                type="Magenerds\PageDesigner\Plugin\Block\WidgetOptionsPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

What is the best way to override my textarea with this module?

Comment: In your extension what you  have try

Comment: The problem is i do not know where to start, I tried to change the di.xml in the magendrs module but it does not work.

Comment: First main question, do I have to change the magenerds module to override my custom module or change my module to use the custom page designer field?

Comment: I suggest you to modif your module, so rest of the development working fine.